# Significance testing for differences in ranges

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics

I have a dataset with two carbon values for each individual from different places. The two values per individual will be different, so I am not interested in a Mann-whitney to tell me whether the C1 stat sig different to C2 for the different locations.

Here is an example of my dataset:

```
Animal1   Forest biome    C1value    C2 value
Animal2   Forest biome    C1value    C2 value
Animal3   Forest biome    C1value    C2 value
Animal4   Forest biome    C1value    C2 value
Animal1   Thicket biome    C1value    C2 value
Animal2   thicket biome    C1value    C2 value
Animal3   Thicket biome    C1value    C2 value
Animal3   Thicket biome    C1value    C2 value
```

I have calculated a range/variance for each group but now I need to say whether it is significant or not.

I noted that the ranges are much tighter for the C1 value per biome, than for the C2 values. Is there a stats test for this?

Comment: How many biomes do you have?